# how to fetch data from firestore with where query in flutter based on user's input in textfield

Tags: flutter, firebase

I am trying to fetch record from Firestore. But Android studio not giving me error or nor correct result.

However if and add condition as a hard code then it gives me proper result. but when I add condition based on user's input. Just like a query select all doctors from table where department is equal to "whatever user put in textfield".

Here is my code

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream:     
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Doctors')
      .where("Department", isEqualTo: t6.text) // 
      .snapshots(),
    builder: (BuildContext context,
        AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {

      if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
      }

      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      }

      // access the documents in the snapshot
      final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents =
          snapshot.data!.docs;

      // build your UI using the data from the snapshot
      return TypeAheadFormField(
        validator: (value) {
          if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
            return 'Please Select Doctor';
          }
          return null;
        },
        suggestionsBoxDecoration: SuggestionsBoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
        textFieldConfiguration: TextFieldConfiguration(
          controller: t7,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
            suffixIcon: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
              onPressed: () {
                t7.clear();
              },
            ),
            label: Text(
              "Search Doctor",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        suggestionsCallback: (query) async {

          // filter the documents based on the query
          final filteredDocuments = documents.where((doc) =>
              doc['Doc_Name']
                  .toLowerCase()
                  .contains(query.toLowerCase()));
          // create a list of suggestions from the filtered documents
          final suggestions = filteredDocuments
              .map((doc) => doc['Doc_Name'])
              .toList();
          return await suggestions;
        },
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, suggestion) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(suggestion),
          );
        },
        onSuggestionSelected: (suggestion) {
          setState(() {
            t7.text = suggestion;
          });
        },
      );
    },
  ),
```

Comment: Where was `t6` used?

Comment: t6 is a TextEditingController controller. and used t6 in query. user will select value from dropdown and the query will show the result according the user selection from dropdown.

Comment: Hmm, try using a String variable, set in the onChanged property of the TextField then call setState...pass this string vairable to the where function.